# SQL Developer 4 Monitor Sessions not working correctly

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I have SQL Developer Version 4.0.0.13 and I am connected to Oracle9i Enterprise Edition Release 9.2.0.8.0.

I try to use the Monitor Sessions from the Tools menu / running the Sessions report under Database Administration -> Sessions and I always get the following error.

```
An error was encountered performing the requested operation:

ORA-00904: "SQL_ID": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Vendor code 904
```

I took the Sessions report copied it to UserDefinedReports and edited it. I found the following:

The report makes a SELECT from gv$session and tries to SELECT a column called SQL_ID which when I do DESC gv$session does not exist.

So I removed the SQL_ID from the select and the whole report and I can run successfully my custom report.

Question is:

Is there a way to make this work for the normal Sessions report and also to work from the Tools drop down menu ? I want to be able to kill sessions and trace them and with the custom report this is not working so I hoped maybe with the standard it should be possible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can either ask your dba to grant you privs on gv$ views, or do this to customize your report to get the kill/trace buttons back.

I talk about that here:

http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2014/04/how-to-add-custom-actions-to-your-user-reports/

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

Login to sqlplus with sys admin, then run these grants for your user:

```
GRANT SELECT ON gv_$session TO payroll;
GRANT SELECT ON gv_$sql TO payroll;
```

My SQL Developer Version: 4.1.0.19

---

**Another solution:**

Define a sys connection in sql developer with sqsdba privileges,
and when it asks for a connection, select that one instead your user:

http://turingsman.net/my-blog-list/158-part-10-configuring-sys-and-system-users-connections-for-sql-developer-in-oracle-database-11gr2-client